# paper-dropdown-menu values are not displayed after using cloneNode()

Tags: polymer

I'm using Polymer to generate a registration form and part of the form can repeat depending on the user input data. This part of the form has a field with a controlled list of values so I tried paper-dropdown-menu. However, when I use cloneNode() to repeat this section of the form the values are not displayed in the repeated form sections. The values are displayed in the cloned node when I use a datalist. Is there a way to use a paper-dropdown-menu in a cloned node or another way to repeat this form section?

Here is the paper-dropdown-menu code:

```
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="HTTP Method" name="httpMethod" required>
      <paper-menu name="select-values" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>GET</paper-item>
        <paper-item>PUT</paper-item>
        <paper-item>POST</paper-item>
        <paper-item>DELETE</paper-item>
      </paper-menu>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Here is the datalist code:

        `<input list="httpMethod" name="HTTP Method" label="HM Test">
          <datalist id="httpMethod">
            <option value="GET">
            <option value="PUT">
            <option value="POST">
            <option value="DELETE">
          </datalist>`

Here is the method to clone the node:

    `repeatDiv: function() {
      var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
      clone = div.cloneNode(true);
      clone.id = "some_id";
      document.getElementById("myDiv").parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't connect the various snippets of code above together to understand what you are doing, but I suspect that you might have timing issues between when the elements are being attached to the DOM and you cloning code.

Rather than clone the code, why not use  to loop stamping out the copy with that.  Or if not dom-repeat, but just one copy, then dom-if.  You can then use databinding and control of the data you are binding to to control how the dom looks.

Comment: The user determines how many times this section of the form repeats so repeatDiv is attached to a button via on-click. How would this work with dom-if?

Comment: So where did you show us that repeatDiv function is attached to a button.  Without the context its difficult to answer properly.  I gave you a couple of options to explore since I couldn't figure out from what you did show us.